# Fill one-dimensional Arraylist with one row of two-dimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I fill one-dimensional `ArrayList` with one row of two-dimensional `ArrayList`? I have tried with following code:

```
public static List<List<Float>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();

public static void buildMatrix(List<String> URLList, List<String> headerList)
{

    // DO SOME STUFF

    List<Float> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    tempArrayList.add(matrix.get(matrix.size()));

}
```

I got an error: "List cannot be applied"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`List#addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) for each element of the `List`

```
List<Float> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<Float> list : matrix) {
    tempArrayList.addAll(list);
}
```

If you use **Java 8**, it can be done thanks to the [`Stream API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), more specifically with the method [`Stream#flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) as next:

```
List<Float> tempArrayList = matrix.stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```